# Looking for examples/cases where mutiple interface inheritance (not implementation) is necessary

Tags: c#, java, interface, multiple-inheritance

Both C# and Java support interfaces inheriting from multiple parents:

```
public interface IMyInterface : IInterface1, IInterface2
```

---

```
public interface MyInterface
extends Interface1, Interface2
```

I've been looking in both the .NET Framework and JavaAPI documentation for examples where multiple interface inheritance is used.

In the JavaAPI I find examples of subinterfaces extending a superinterface and one or more "marker" interfaces (i.e. they have no defined methods). So the "marker" interfaces aren't really enforcing anything on the implementation. I can see the benefit of this, especially before annotations were introduced.

In .NET I find interfaces inheriting from multiple parents that are already related. For instance `IList` inherits from `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` but `ICollection` is already a descendant of `IEnumerable`. So enforcing `IEnumerable` on an implementation is already accomplished with single inheritance.

In either case it looks like the multiple interface inheritance is either redundant or could be replaced by a better alternative.

Are there any examples that would be difficult or impossible to accomplish without multiple interface inheritance?

Comment: `MySepcialInterface` that should be both `Cloneable` and `Comparable`?

Comment: Well, yes but I was looking for a real justification for wanting an interface that extends two unrelated interfaces. As I mentioned above the Java examples I've found were "markers" and the .NET examples I found would've already been enforced through single inheritance.

Comment: No design is going to be impossible or even difficult to implement without multiple interface inheritance. The practice just promotes decoupling and separation of concerns, which certainly isn't mandatory for something to work (just makes it cleaner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the way you were describing the .NET interface inheritance chain, then you're incorrect.  It's an easy mistake to make, since the documentation makes it look that way.  `IList<T>` only explicitly inherits from `ICollection<T>`; it *does not* inherit from `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`.  Here's the actual definition from the reference source:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>
```

The same goes for `ICollection<T>`, it only inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.  During compilation, the inheritance tree is flattened and deduplicated, in a sense, for interfaces.  So, an interface that inherits `ICollection` doesn't just inherit that interface, which, in turn, inherits `IEnumerable`.  Rather, the interface will inherit `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` itself.

Visual example:

```
IMine : ICollection<T> != IMine : (ICollection<T>:(IEnumerable<T>:IEnumerable))
```

Instead, it looks like this compiled:

```
IMine: ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Which explains why you've drawn the conclusion that you have.

---

As for a real world example of multiple interface inheritance, look at the `IQueryable` and `IOrderedQueryable` examples.  The actual source declaration of these interfaces is as follows:

```
public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable {}
public interface IOrderedQueryable<out T> : IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable {}
```

`IQueryable` needs to have a contract that specifies that you can iterate over each element, but also the ability to be differentiated from a simple `IEnumerable` in that it alone, not all `IEnumerable` types, can be used in an `IQueryProvider` and the static `Queryable` class.

---

Another fun one is in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

```
public interface IProducerConsumerCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection
```

It's interesting because it inherits from `ICollection` (non-generic) and `IEnumerable<T>` which both inherit from `IEnumerable`.  Of course, this isn't a problem, but it's another good example.  If `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` were to inherit from `ICollection<T>` instead of its non-generic counterpart, I'm sure that it wouldn't explicitly inherit from `IEnumerable<T>`. It has the size, (old)enumerator and synchronization methods behavior defined in `ICollection`, and then also the generic enumeration behavior defined in `IEnumerable<T>`

There's two examples.  There are more I've found, but I think these are probably enough.

Comment: Now that's closer to what I'm looking for. `IQueryable<T>` inherits from two sibling interfaces that have a common parent (`IEnumerable`) but neither inherits from the other. And you were correct, I was basing my assumptions on the msdn documentation and Redgate Reflector. Both make it appear as though each interface directly inherits from each of its ancestors using multiple inheritance.

Comment: So multiple interface inheritance can be used as a way to enforce a design constraint onto an implementing object. If C# or Java only supported single inheritance of interfaces there'd be no way to enforce that an object must implement two interfaces.

Comment: Well, your first sentence described the purpose of interfaces in general.  Interfaces are ways of saying a class behaves in 'this way'.  I don't like to think of interface inheritance as such, I like to think it's closer to composition, you're essentially including those contracts in the class.  You could still enforce a single class to have two interfaces by giving them separately, but then you'd have to do that to all interfaces.  You can do accomplish the same thing in different ways aside from multiple inheritance, but it's less maintainable and uglier.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [the Interface Segregation Principle (ISP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) from the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29). Basically, you should create small interfaces that plug together rather than trying to look for a way to combine them. Why have methods that are not useful to some classes being forced? That is usually the reason for multiple inheritance.

As to whether a design would be impossible, I would say no as you could just create a giant interface. However, the ISP points out the negativity of this approach, which *would* make maintenance a potential difficulty, but off of an initial design, I would say no you do not need multiple inheritance to complete an implementation. It just might look messy is all

Comment: I'm familiar with the ISP and SOLID principles and in general I agree with them. I'm looking for examples where a design would be difficult or impossible without multiple interface inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the objects implementing your interface to be both **IDisposable** and **IComparable**.

For instance if you have a collection of resources you might want to order or filter them (using IEquatable) based on some of their properties. This means that all the objects have to implement both interfaces and you could use a common interface to enforce this

```
IResource<T>: IDisposable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
```

Comment: Can you give examples of when you'd actually want to do that? Seems like comparable would be a value and disposable a resource reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

`Comparable` is often something you want separate from the main type.

`AbstractList` subtypes both `AbstractCollection` and `List`.

`StringBuilder` is both a `CharSequence` (a read interface) and an `Appendable` (a write interface). I'm not too keen on merging the read and write together like that - immutable values and tell-don't-ask interfaces.

Obviously there are (largely evil) marker interfaces: `Serializable`, `Cloneable` and `RandomAccess`.

GUI code in particular tends to have completely unnecessary implementation of callback interfaces into one bug class, which usually extends a class it had no reason to.

Comment: The examples you gave were all classes that implement multiple interfaces. I was looking for examples of interfaces that extend multiple interfaces. I finally found an example in java.nio.channels.ByteChannel but there's no justification given for combining ReadableByteChannel and WritableByteChannel into a single interface.